# How to run timer according to commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

```
import time
import os

T = int(input("Enter desired time for the timer - "))
t = time.localtime(time.time())

def Timer():
    while ((t.tm_sec) != T+(t.tm_sec)):
        return t
    else:
        os.system("start C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music")


Timer()
```

I have been working on this timer and can't get it to work. Basically, I want it to play the song I have in my system when the time is up. I have been trying to write this program and I can't understand why my code doesn't run the way I want it to. Could someone please point out if there's a mistake in it?

Comment: What is the exact error/issue/incorrect behaviour that you are facing?

Comment: When would you expect `(t.tm_sec)` to be equal to `T+(t.tm_sec)`? If `T` is nonzero this will never be true. Also, once you hit `return`, your `Timer()` function ends and your program is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your example makes proper use of `while` (and `return`). How about a much simpler version:

```py
import time
import os

T = int(input("Enter desired time for the timer - "))

def Timer():
     time.sleep(T)
     os.system("start C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music")

Timer()
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your code specifically is this condition

```py
(t.tm_sec) != T+(t.tm_sec)
```

The problem is that `t`'s value was set when you did `(t.tm_sec) != T+(t.tm_sec)`. Once that is set, the same value of t will be used. I think you assumed that `t` will be recomputed every time in the while statement. To recompute `t` every time you can do:

```py
import time
import os

T = int(input("Enter desired time for the timer - "))
snap_time = time.localtime(time.time())

def Timer():
    t = time.localtime(time.time())
    while t.tm_sec < (T + snap_time.tm_sec):
        t = time.localtime(time.time())

    os.system("start C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music")


Timer()
```

Answer (score 0):

`t.tm_sec` is fixed, so unless `T` is 0 the condition will never be `False`, so the `else` block will never be executed. On top of that there is `return` in the loop, which mean it will run only one iteration and exit the function. Try

```
T = int(input("Enter desired time for the timer - ")) + time.time()

def Timer():
    while time.time() < T:
        pass
    else:
        os.system("start C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music")
```

You can also remove the `else`

```
def Timer():
    while time.time() < T:
        pass
    os.system("start C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music")
```